# MongoDB $lookup with array of ObjectId

Tags: arrays, mongodb, lookup, objectid

I'm working on a MongoDB model to hold photos (/videos). Each file can (optionally) appear in one or more albums. My model looks like this:

```
> db.files.find().pretty()
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("600725fbba9901ec2caeba5f"),
        "filename" : "first_picture.jpg",
        "type" : "image",
        "added" : 1611081211,
        "views" : 9,
        "tags" : [ ],
        "albums" : [
            ObjectId("6007d8cfc3b7ef3895f0a8d3")
        ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("600729cf087c3cf47becee3c"),
        "filename" : "first_video.mp4",
        "type" : "video",
        "added" : 1611082191,
        "views" : 1,
        "tags" : [ ],
        "albums" : [ ]
    }
```

```
> db.albums.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6007d8cfc3b7ef3895f0a8d3"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "created" : 0
}
```

What I'm trying to do is use $lookup to create a single document returned with the `album` document and the documents from the `files` collection that have that `album`'s ObjectId in the albums array. Since I don't want to load all the files at once, I want to limit the number of files entries I get back.

My current query looks like this:

```
db.albums.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup:{
      from: "files",
      let: { "albums": "$albums" },
      pipeline: [
        { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$albums"] } } },
      ],
      as: "file_list"
    }
  }
])
```

From the examples I've seen, this *should* work. But when I run the query I get:

```
2021-01-20T13:44:42.779-0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing",
    "code" : 40081,
    "codeName" : "Location40081"
} : aggregate failed :
```

This suggests the albums field is not an array, but it is - and it's present in both documents. What am I doing wrong? I'm pulling my hair out!

**Edit:**
Expected output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6007d8cfc3b7ef3895f0a8d3"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "created" : 0.
    "files": [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("600725fbba9901ec2caeba5f"),
            "filename" : "first_picture.jpg",
            "type" : "image",
            "added" : 1611081211,
            "views" : 9,
            "tags" : [ ],
            "albums" : [
                ObjectId("6007d8cfc3b7ef3895f0a8d3")
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post what is your expected output? Because If I've understood correctly, you `$lookup` should be in the other way: from `files` to `albums`.

Comment: Good point, I've added what I'm expecting as my output document

Answer (score 0):

I misinterpreted the documentation.

It occurred to me that the variables defined in `$let` could be referring to the main document, rather than the documents being joined. My confusion was around the use of *input document*, which I took to be the collection being joined, when it actually means the collection in `db.collection.aggregate`. This is why the array doesn't exist, it's not in the `albums` document, it's in the `files` document.

The correct query is:

```
db.albums.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup:{
      from: "files",
      let: { "id": "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$$id", "$albums"] } } },
      ],
      as: "file_list"
    }
  }
])
```

The response is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6008fdce422871592e927b0a"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "created" : 0,
    "file_list" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6008fe2c422871592e927b0b"),
            "filename" : "first_picture.jpg",
            "type" : "image",
            "added" : 1611081211,
            "views" : 9,
            "tags" : [ ],
            "albums" : [
                ObjectId("6008fdce422871592e927b0a")
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```